# Cannot install certain games on Genymotion's Google Play

Tags: google-play, genymotion

I just freshly installed Genymotion on Archlinux, and then installed Google Play with Genymotion's built-in Open G-Apps icon from their toolbar. I've created custom devices with the resolutions I like and Google Nexus 10, with 6 cores and 8 GB of RAM at most. But yet, Google Play Store says the device is incompatible to install Mobile Legends Adventure. I only have 6 cores and 16 GB of RAM so I tried to give all but it seemed like it wasn't enough. Is there any other factor for Google Play Store that I should consider? The device is Android 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably means that Mobile Legends Adventure is for ARM CPU only. See https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002676057